# Slack API (files.upload) using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, slack-api

**EDITED**

I'm trying to structure the [files.upload() API](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) provided via Slack but am having a hard time understanding the correct format.  At the moment, I am able to use the API to upload a text file but cannot for the life of me figure out how to upload an image.

Here's my issue:  I have an image on my development server, let's call it image.png.  I want to use the files.upload() API to post that image into a #general Slack channel.  Below is the code I have that is successfully generating the image, but currently is just sending the text:

```
        var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
        var myBarChartDataURL = leaderboardBarChart.toBase64Image();

        canvas.toBuffer(function(err, buf) {
          if (err) throw err;
          fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/leaderboard.png", buf);
        });

        bot.api.files.upload({
          token: process.env.token,
          title: "Image",
          filename: "image.png",
          filetype: "auto",
          //content: "Posted with files.upload API",
          file: fs.createReadStream("path/to/image_file.png"),
          channels: filtered[0].id
        }, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error (files.upload) " + err);
          } else {
            console.log("Success (files.upload) " + response);
          };
        });
```

When I run the code I get one of the following error:

"invalid_array_arg" which Slack details as:  "*The method was passed a PHP-style array argument (e.g. with a name like foo[7]). These are never valid with the Slack API*."

I'm not entirely sure what to make of this error as I'm not using PHP nor anything that I can identify that would be PHP-like.

I've experimented with several different approaches for including the file path, whether using the 'fs' module, storing it in a variable, or just referencing it's absolute path (and even a relative path).  I'm a bit lost and am just looking for some guidance.

I understand that this particular API uses multipart/form-data but I don't have a form.  This app is strictly a NodeJS app.  There is no framework (like Express) working in tandem with the main node script.

Any and all help is really appreciated.  Again, just looking for some insight/guidance on what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you tell us what `bot.api` is? I'm just guessing based on variable names, but maybe you're using [botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit)?

Comment: If it is indeed botkit, I think `file: fs.createReadStream("path/to/image/file")` might do the trick. (Botkit uses [request](https://github.com/request/request), which handles `multipart/form-data` via [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data)).

Comment: I am using botkit!  I will try that out, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: When I do that, I keep getting an error saying "invalid_array_arg".  Could it have anything to do with how I'm generating the image?  (See below):


           canvas.toBuffer(function(err, buf) {
              if (err) throw err;
              fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/image.png", buf);
            });

Comment: Could you update the question with your current code and the details of the error you're seeing?

Comment: @smarx absolutely, just did!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to go outside of Botkit's API here, since Botkit doesn't seem to support sending `multipart/form-data`.

Give this a try, using `request` directly (already in use by Botkit itself):

```
var request = require('request');

...

request.post({
    url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
    formData: {
        token: bot.config.token,
        title: "Image",
        filename: "image.png",
        filetype: "auto",
        channels: filtered[0].id,
        file: fs.createReadStream('test.png'),
    },
}, function (err, response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
});
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help.  Your suggested answer worked flawlessly.  Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible to send directly to a user instead of a channel? I see that docs only talk about sending to channel

Comment: FYI...I just got the original request (using bot.api.files.upload) to work.  It appears there was a fix in Botkit v0.4.1.

See https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/commit/2bde51ff5326ccc44b8764ecc3110dac6696ef6c for details

Comment: @dimirc yes, just use the ID of the user as channel and it will be uploaded directly to him in the Slackbot channel

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using the [nodejslack](https://github.com/marcogbarcellos/nodejslack).
It uses the Promises pattern, powered by [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) .
There is a sample code for uploading file in its documentations, here it is:

```
    var Slack = require('nodejslack');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var SLACK_TOKEN = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN || 'YOUR_GENERATED_SLACK_TOKEN';

    var slack = new Slack(SLACK_TOKEN);

    var form = {
      file: fs.createReadStream('test.csv'), // Optional, via multipart/form-data. If omitting this parameter, you MUST submit content 
      // content: 'Your text here', // Optional, File contents. If omitting this parameter, you must provide a `file`  
      filename: 'test.csv', // Required  
      fileType: 'post', // Optional, See more file types in https://api.slack.com/types/file#file_types 
      title: 'Title of your file!', // Optional 
      initial_comment: 'First comment about this file.', // Optional 
      channels: 'general' //Optional, If you want to put more than one channel, separate using comma, example: 'general,random' 
    };

    slack.fileUpload(form)
    .then(function(response){

        // Slack sends a json with a boolean var ok.  
        // Error example : data = { ok: false, error: 'user_not_found'         } 
        // Error example : data = { ok: true, file: 'user_not_found' } 
        if(!response || !response.ok){
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Something wrong happened during the upload.'));
        }
        console.log('Uploaded Successfully:',response);

        return Promise.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        return err;
    });
```