# How to upload an image to Slack using node.js on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to upload an image via Slack using node.js and the [request package](https://github.com/request/request), but not having much luck. Either I receive `invalid_array_arg` or `no_file_data` errors from the API.

Here is my request:

```
    var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
      headers: 
       { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
         'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      form: 
       { token: SLACK_TOKEN,
         channels: SLACK_CHANNEL,
         file: fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log(body);
    });
```

I had a look at a few relevant posts:

- [Can I upload an image as attachment with Slack API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994070/can-i-upload-an-image-as-attachment-with-slack-api)
- [Slack API (files.upload) using NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084459/slack-api-files-upload-using-nodejs)
- [fix files.upload from Buffer with formData options #307](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/307#issuecomment-289231737)

The only thing that worked was using the curl command directly, but using cygwin (CommandPrompt failed: `curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`). The issue calling curl from node (using `child_process`) but that silently fails in Command Prompt and still returns `no_file_data` using cygwin (passing an absolute path to the file):

```
stdout: {"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}
stderr:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   469  100    35  100   434    359   4461 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6112
```

I'm using node v6.9.1 on Windows.

What am I missing ? How can I upload an image to slack via node.js on Windows ?

Comment: I know this is not answer for your question, maybe you should consider to use [node-slack-sdk/](https://slackapi.github.io/node-slack-sdk/), in that case you don't need to implement these feature for yourself. [file upload documentation](https://slackapi.github.io/node-slack-sdk/web_api#uploading-a-file)

Comment: @Peter surprisingly getting the same error with the node-slack-sdk:`error: Response not OK:  no_file_data
Error: no_file_data`

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza the way to go is [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload).

Comment: why is the solution from your #2 linked question not working for your? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084459/slack-api-files-upload-using-nodejs) have you tried to reproduce with the same syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack API (files.upload) using NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084459/slack-api-files-upload-using-nodejs)

Comment: what `fs.createReadStream(filepath).stat()`  says?

Comment: anyway [this](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/307#issuecomment-289231737) looks relevant too.

Comment: @Peter `console.log(fs.createReadStream(filename).stat());
                                          ^

TypeError: fs.createReadStream(...).stat is not a function`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I've mentioned in my question I already checked out the question you've marked as a duplicate. I admit they are very similar, but the solution there does not work in my case. Even though the error at the end is the same, the source of the error might be different.

Comment: How about trying this sample script? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/40c9284e91d209356395b43022ffc5cc In my environment, your script also occurs the same error. So I created this. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike the first explicit multipart header worked like charm! You should post this as an answer as well: it's super useful! Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm glad this was useful for you. I posted this script. Please confirm it.

Comment: If you have problems for my sample script, please tell me. I would like to study from the problems.

Comment: @Tanaike I wish I could give you more than one vote. Both solutions worked ! In the meantime I've ran more tests and found the problem: I tried to upload an image before it was fully written to disk. Once I ensure the file is fully written to disk, the second method works too. What's interesting is that your first method, manually creating the multipart header worked even when the image wasn't fully written to disk: it simply displayed gray pixels for the missing data.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your problem was solved. And also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeProfenza, I'm running into the same error and I was wondering how you ensured that your image was fully written to disk. You said " I tried to upload an image before it was fully written to disk. Once I ensure the file is fully written to disk" that the methods worked. I'm trying to send a PDF as a opposed to an image but I am getting the same error and I have a feeling it's for the same reason

Comment: @CarolGonzalez In my case, I was downloading a couple of images, using graphics magick to make a montage of them, then upload the result, so in my case starting the upload process from `gm`'s `'close'` event. In your case it might be even listener available when the pdf file completed writing to disk. As a proof of concept you can try a hacky `setTimeout` to 10 seconds or something (if the PDF isn't huge) to isolate the issue and confirm it's the same issue. If that's the case ideally you would remove the hacky delay and use the correct event. Sorry about the delay in getting back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Slack API error `invalid_array_arg` means that there is a problem with the format of the arguments passed to Slack. (see [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload#errors))

When using the `file` property for `files.upload`, Slack excepts the data as `multipart/form-data`, not as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So instead of `form`, you need to use `formData` in your request object. I also removed the incorrect part in the header.

This works:

```
      var fs = require('fs');
      var request = require('request');

      var SLACK_TOKEN = "xoxp-xxx";
      var SLACK_CHANNEL = "general";
      var filepath = "file.txt";

      var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
      headers: 
       { 'cache-control': 'no-cache' },
      formData: 
       { token: SLACK_TOKEN,
         channels: SLACK_CHANNEL,
         file: fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log(body);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried using `formData` as you suggested above, unfortunately I'm getting the same error. I will run a few more tests. Perhaps the data I'm uploading isn't ready ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza This code is tested and works. I have added the initialization just to make sure. Have you tried this exact code? And please let me know what error you are getting from the API exactly.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I did some further tests and found the source of the  problem: not the request itself, but the data and createReadStream results. 
I didn't wait for the image I was uploading to be fully written to disk before uploading. That is fixed now and both your code and Tanaike's code work. The interesting thing about his manual multipart approach is that it worked even when the jpeg wasn't fully written to disk (displaying the jpeg at the correct dimensions with a small portion of grey pixels)

Answer (score 2):

In this sample script, it supposes to upload a binary file (zip file). When you use this, please modify for your environment. When files are uploaded to Slack, multipart/form-data is used. In my environment, there were the situations that files couldn't be uploaded by some libraries. So I created this. If this is useful for your environment, I'm glad.

Users can upload the binary file by converting byte array as follows.

- At first, it builds form-data.
- Adds the zip file converted to byte array and boundary using Buffer.concat().
- This is used as body in request.

The sample script is as follows.

### Sample script :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var upfile = 'sample.zip';
fs.readFile(upfile, function(err, content){
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
    var metadata = {
        token: "### access token ###",
        channels: "sample",
        filename: "samplefilename",
        title: "sampletitle",
    };
    var url = "https://slack.com/api/files.upload";
    var boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var data = "";
    for(var i in metadata) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(metadata, i)) {
            data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
            data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + i + "\"; \r\n\r\n" + metadata[i] + "\r\n";
        }
    };
    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + upfile + "\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    var payload = Buffer.concat([
            Buffer.from(data, "utf8"),
            new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
            Buffer.from("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n", "utf8"),
    ]);
    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary},
        body: payload,
    };
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```