# no_file_data response in slack file upload

Tags: node.js, axios, query-string, slack-api

I'm using node.js to try to upload a csv file via slackAPI's upload file method. The method is post. I'm unsure how to make this possible because if I use the content argument instead of the file, I get the error:

```
{ ok: false, error: 'invalid_array_arg' }
```

If I use the file aargument, I still get the error:

```
{ ok: false, error: 'invalid_array_arg' }
```

There are multiple fault points in this code and I've tried to test each one but I'm sure I'm missing some information here. Here's the uploadFile Method that I created:

```
function uploadFile(file){
    console.log(botToken);
    axios.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', qs.stringify({token: botToken, file: file, channels: 'testing'}))
        .then(function (response) {
             var serverMessage = response.data;
             console.log(serverMessage);
             console.log("inside file upload function");
})
}
```

here's how I call the method:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + csvFilePath);   // <--make sure this path is correct
    console.log(__dirname + '/' + csvFilePath);
    uploadFile(file);
```

And finally the output:

Bot has started!
C:\Users\i502153\WebstormProjects\slackAPIProject/accessLogs/CSV/1548430592860output.csv*
    { ok: false, error: 'invalid_array_arg' }
    inside file upload function

What am I doing wrong and how to rectify this?

Links:
https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution won't work because you are attempting to take a *stream object* (`file`) and stringify it into a query string, which is just going to insert the nonsense string "[object]" into the query. It won't actually stream data to Slack.

Axios, unfortunately, doesn't work in node exactly like it does in the browser, and their docs can be a little confusing.

I would suggest an approach like this (untested):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

function uploadFile(file) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('token', botToken);
    form.append('channels, 'testing');
    form.append('file', file, 'optionalfilenamehere');
    return axios.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', form, {
        headers: form.getHeaders()
    }).then(function (response) {
        var serverMessage = response.data;
        console.log(serverMessage);
        console.log('inside file upload function');
    });
}
```

I adapted this code from the suggestion in ticket https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006#issuecomment-320165427, there may be other helpful comments there as well if you run into issues. Good luck!

EDIT: For people reading this later, for a similar approach using `request` instead of `axios`, see related question [Slack API (files.upload) using NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084459/slack-api-files-upload-using-nodejs).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!